# Writing to derived data in an archived app

Tags: macos, cocoa

I produced a .aiff file in my app and it's in my derived data folder, somewhere deep in the /Library. When I run the app in Xcode everything works fine. However when I archive it, the program crashes when it tries to write. How do I solve this? Do I need to learn to use Core Data or is there a easy fix?

Comment: Are you sure you mean "derived data"? That's where Xcode keeps its build products, not a place your app would know about or write to.

Comment: Oops... I definitely meant derived data, but I didn't know an app can't access them. What should I use instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to write to the current working directory?

(If you're trying to do something like `[foo writeToFile:@"output.aiff" …]`, you are.)

When you run within Xcode, the CWD is the build products directory within DerivedData where your application's bundle gets created.

When you run outside of Xcode, the CWD is the root of the startup disk, which you do not ordinarily have write access to and should never touch without explicit orders and permission to do from the user (via an Open panel or similar).

Either way, the CWD is the wrong place to put things.

You probably should [run a Save panel](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSavePanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSSavePanel/beginSheetModalForWindow%3acompletionHandler%3a), then write the file in your completion handler to [the URL the Save panel has for you](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSavePanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSSavePanel/URL).

If you want to stash the file in some constant directory, [ask an NSFileManager for](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/URLForDirectory%3ainDomain%3aappropriateForURL%3acreate%3aerror%3a) the [Caches folder](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSSearchPathDirectory) in [the user domain](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSSearchPathDomainMask) (~/Library/Caches), then tell it to create a folder inside that folder whose name is your main bundle's `bundleIdentifier`, then write the file in that directory.